# How can I change animation-timing-function for Slide component in MaterialUi react

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, material-ui

First time using transitions in [material-ui]

Wondering if anyone has changed animation-timing-function in Slide component of Materia-Ui react ?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted change animation function for Slide component and I ended up with customizing the theme

```
theme = createMuiTheme({

    transitions: {
        easing: {
            easeInOut: 'linear',
            easeOut: 'linear',
            easeIn: 'linear',
            sharp: 'linear'
        },
    }
});

export { theme };
```